# Export Last N block

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands, blockchain-export

It is possible to export the first N blocks using option `--block-stop` in  `monero-blockchain-export`.

Is it possible to export the **last** N blocks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

.... more characters.... Because stupid limit...